# Python Find All Adjacent Subsets of Set of Coins Which Have a Tails Minority

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity

Given a sequence of heads and tails I want to find how many significant subsequences are in this sequence where the number of heads is not less than the number of tails. I want to achieve this in \$O(N \log N)\$ time.

**Example input:**
`[ 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H' ]`

**Example output:**

```
11
```

**Explanation:**

```
{H} {H} {H}
{H, T} {T, H} {H, T} {T, H}
{H, T, H} 
{H, T, H, T} 
{H, T, T, H} 
{H, T, H, T, T, H}
```

I believe my current algorithm is \$O(N^2)\$. I solve the problem recursively, iterating with the list of coins sliced on either end.

Here is my current algorithm. Am I correct that this is \$O(N^2)\$ and is not \$O(N \log N)\$?

```
def count_sequences( data ):
    print go(range(0,len(data)),data)
seen = set()
def go(rang,data):
    if tuple(rang) in seen: return 0
    seen.add(tuple(rang))
    h = 0
    summ = 0
    if len(rang)==0: return 0
    for i in rang:
        if data[i] == 'H': h += 1
        summ += go(rang[1:],data)
        summ += go(rang[:-1],data)
    if len(rang) == 1: 
        if h ==1: return 1
        else: return 0
    if h > (len(rang)-1)/2 : 
        return 1 + summ
    else: return summ
```

Comment: I think you have used ["subsequence"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) where you meant "substring".

Comment: This post was crossposted on StackOverflow. There I wrote a O(n) solution to this problem that may be useful for anyone looking in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32085200/1327235

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`go` has these costs:

```
                                     O(x)
def go(rang,data):
    if tuple(rang) in seen: return 0   n
    seen.add(tuple(rang))              n
    h = 0                              1
    summ = 0                           1
    if len(rang)==0: return 0          1
    for i in rang:                     n (
        if data[i] == 'H': h += 1         1
        summ += go(rang[1:],data)         n + T(n-1)
        summ += go(rang[:-1],data)        n + T(n-1)
    if len(rang) == 1:                 ) 1
        if h ==1: return 1             1
        else: return 0                 1
    if h > (len(rang)-1)/2 :           1
        return 1 + summ                1
    else: return summ                  1
```

You call this once for each sub-tuple of `data`, and there are at least this many of those:

$$
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n-1) + n
$$

Because there are \$1\$ for length \$n\$, \$2\$ for length \$n-1\$, etc. There's one more for length 0, but that's uninteresting.

Each should be multiplied by its cost; if you consider only those that succeed (not those which are caught by `seen`), they cost \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ each due to

```
    for i in rang:                     n (
        if data[i] == 'H': h += 1         1
        summ += go(rang[1:],data)         n + T(n-1)
        summ += go(rang[:-1],data)        n + T(n-1)
                                       )
```

The calls are not part of this; only the looping and the slicing. This gives a cost of

$$
1(n)^2 + 2(n-1)^2 + 3(n-2)^2 + ... + (n-1)(2)^2 + n(1)^21
$$

or

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k (n-k+1)^2 = \frac{1}{12} n (n+1) (n^2+3 n+2)
$$

which is \$\mathcal{O}(n^4)\$. So caching does improve this a lot from \$\mathcal{O}(2^n n!)\$... but not nearly enough.

Note that we could prove that it's valid to ignore failed calls by moving the `if tuple(rang) in seen` check into the caller and seeing that the cost is the same.

Using range objects like Python 3's `range` would give costs of \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ each, not \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$, since slicing would be \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$. However, the check `if tuple(rang) in seen` prevents this from mattering. You can see this by moving the check into the caller. If you changed this to `if rang in seen` using an \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ hash, this would work and reduce the cost to \$\mathcal{O}(n^3)\$ overall. Math elided for brevity.

---

We can test this experimentally like:

```
import time

def times(iters):
    for n in range(iters):
        heads = ['H'] * (2**n)
        seen.clear()

        s = time.time()
        count_sequences(heads)
        print((time.time() - s) * 10**5)

times(8)
```

Giving

```
0.691413879395
1.00135803223
3.48091125488
14.9011611938
90.2891159058
759.696960449
7593.48869324
87769.818306
```

We expect for \$\mathcal{O}(n^4)\$ that a doubling of size will give a factor-of-16 change; we instead see closer to a factor-of-12 change, or \$\mathcal{O}(n^{3.6})\$. This is probably partially because slices are fast relative to interpreter overhead. As \$n\$ increases, this will likely change.

When testing with Python 3 ranges, one gets

```
1.0251998901367188
1.1444091796875
3.5762786865234375
19.14501190185547
123.23856353759766
878.2625198364258
6614.780426025391
51359.89189147949
414633.48865509033
```

which is almost perfectly \$\mathcal{O}(n^3)\$.

---

Your code should use spacing. Note how when you posted this question you used paragraphs with line breaks. The same this helps with code. You should also stick to PEP 8.

Just changing that and using brackets on `print` gives

```
def count_sequences(data):
    print(go(range(0, len(data)), data))

seen = set()
def go(range_, data):
    if tuple(range_) in seen:
        return 0

    seen.add(tuple(range_))

    h = 0
    summ = 0
    if not range_:
        return 0

    for i in range_:
        if data[i] == 'H':
            h += 1

        summ += go(range_[1:],data)
        summ += go(range_[:-1],data)

    if len(range_) == 1: 
        if h == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    if h > (len(range_) - 1) / 2: 
        return 1 + summ

    else:
        return summ
```

I would use a better name than `rang`/`range_`; probably `indices`. However, best use two integers: `start`/`stop`. `count_sequences` should `return` rather then `print`. Further, a little cleanup gives

```
def count_sequences(data):
    return go(data, 0, len(data))

seen = set()
def go(data, start, stop):
    if (start, stop) in seen:
        return 0

    seen.add((start, stop))

    h = 0
    summ = 0
    if start == stop:
        return 0

    for i in xrange(start, stop):
        if data[i] == 'H':
            h += 1

        summ += go(data, start+1, stop)
        summ += go(data, start, stop-1)

    if stop - start == 1: 
        return h

    if h > (stop - start - 1) / 2: 
        summ += 1

    return summ
```

Then consider that

```
summ += go(data, start+1, stop)
summ += go(data, start, stop-1)
```

is a loop invariant, so move it out.

And

```
for i in xrange(start, stop):
    if data[i] == 'H':
        h += 1
```

can be

```
h = data[start:stop].count('H')
```

You can make `data[start:stop].count('H')`, the only remaining \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ aspect, faster by replacing `data` with a list of cumulative counts and doing

```
h = counts[stop] - counts[start]
```

This should reduce the cost to just \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ overall; constant cost for each subsequence.

This doesn't do anything so remove it:

```
if stop - start == 1: 
    return h
```

This then gives

```
def count_sequences(data):
    counts = [0]
    for item in data:
        counts.append(counts[-1] + (item == 'H'))

    return go(counts, 0, len(data))

seen = set()
def go(counts, start, stop):
    if start == stop:
        return 0

    if (start, stop) in seen:
        return 0
    seen.add((start, stop))

    h = counts[stop] - counts[start]

    summ = go(counts, start+1, stop) + go(counts, start, stop-1)
    if h > (stop - start - 1) / 2: 
        summ += 1

    return summ
```

---

## Simplifying

The first step in simplifying is to consider

```
h = counts[stop] - counts[start]

if h > (stop - start - 1) / 2: 
    summ += 1
```

This can be reduced to

```
if counts[stop] - counts[start] >= 0: 
    summ += 1
```

by making `'T'` count as `-1`. Then any subsection with more heads than tails will have a positive total.

This simplifies the whole code to

```
from itertools import combinations

def count_sequences(data):
    counts = [0]
    for item in data:
        counts.append(counts[-1] + (1 if item == 'H' else -1))

    return sum(end >= start for start, end in combinations(counts, 2))
```

This is still \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ but it's also much faster and has no recursion limit.

---

This gives us the secret for how to do this in \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$. We want to do this fast:

```
sum(end >= start for start, end in combinations(counts, 2))
```

Let's say you have a list `counts` as so:

```
[1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0]
```

You look at the list in two parts:

```
[1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2]   [3, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0]
```

You know `f(first_half)` and `f(second_half)`, so you want to find

```
sum(end >= start for start, end in product(first_half, second_half))
```

Unfortunately, the above is no faster than the naïve method. However, you can do merge sort with `f(first_half)` and `f(second_half)` in \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$ time, so you can instead have

```
[-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]   [-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Then

```
sum(end >= start for start, end in product(first_half, second_half))
```

can be optimized by making a single pass:

```
def sum_across(first_half, second_half):
    total = 0
    snd_idx = 0

    for i in first_half:
        while second_half[snd_idx] < i:
            snd_idx += 1

            if snd_idx == len(second_half):
                return total

        total += len(second_half) - snd_idx

    return total
```

All in all, this gives:

```
from heapq import merge

def sum_across(first_half, second_half):
    total = 0
    snd_idx = 0

    for i in first_half:
        while second_half[snd_idx] < i:
            snd_idx += 1

            if snd_idx == len(second_half):
                return total

        total += len(second_half) - snd_idx

    return total

def count_sequences(data):
    counts = [0]
    for item in data:
        counts.append(counts[-1] + (1 if item == 'H' else -1))

    def recurse(ns):
        if len(ns) <= 1:
            return ns, 0

        mid_point = len(ns) // 2
        first_half, second_half = ns[:mid_point], ns[mid_point:]

        fst_sorted, count_fst = recurse(first_half)
        snd_sorted, count_snd = recurse(second_half)

        count = count_fst + count_snd + sum_across(fst_sorted, snd_sorted)
        ns_sorted = list(merge(fst_sorted, snd_sorted))

        return ns_sorted, count

    counts_sorted, count = recurse(counts)
    return count

count_sequences([ 'H', 'T', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H' ])
#>>> 11
```

Answer (score 4):

It's much worse than you suspected.  For every problem of size \$n\$, you convert it to \$n\$ problems, each of size \$n - 1\$.

Let \$T(n)\$ be the number of times you might run the `if data[i] == 'H'` check.  (For simplicity, we'll ignore the `seen` check for now.)

$$ T(n) = 1 + 2 \cdot n \cdot T(n-1) $$

where \$T(0) = 0\$.  Filling in the numbers,

$$\begin{array}{r|r}
n & T(n) \\
\hline
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & 5 \\
3 & 31 \\
4 & 249 \\
5 & 2491 \\
6 & 29893 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
\end{array}$$

It's much worse than \$O(n^2)\$ — worse than even \$O(2^{2n})\$ — I think it's \$O((2n)!)\$.

Note that you're using both iteration and recursion, which is a bit odd, and helps to disguise the complexity.

In practice, the `seen` check will terminate a lot of the recursion, but even that check has a cost.  It still has to store every single substring it has encountered.  Furthermore, the lookup wouldn't be constant-time, as computing the hash value of a long string would require iterating through each element of the string.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T(n)+%3D+1+%2B+2n+T(n-1)

Comment: I've simplified the above to \$\mathcal{O}(2^n n!)\$.

Comment: You can't just ignore `seen` for simplicty. If you think about it well enough, only \$O(n^2)\$ calls will actually be computed, because that's the order of all possible `rang` values.